# App Script / Google Sheet - How to transfer data to another sheet that is inserted to a template

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

What I'm trying to do is to fill out a form and then once the save button is click it is save below and can be printed to another sheet ,wherein, it fills a fix template ready for printing. The transferred data to the template may vary depending on the need. For example, 2 employee or 1 employees per certificate.

Sample

[image]

Print

[image]

Thank you for your help and guidance.

Sample

[image]

Print

[image]

Thank you for your help and guidance.

Comment: you should use named ranges for template purposes

Comment: You can get all of the data from the form with getValues() and an array literal assignment and then use setValues() to copy it to another sheet.